# Create explanation(s) box for radio button form with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, error-handling, radio-button

I'll use a simplified version below but am trying to build a form with simple yes/no questions. If the answer is no, no explanation is required. If the answer is yes, a new table row is inserted and textarea appears requiring an explanation for that particular question.

Of note, I use the [jQuery validate plugin](http:////ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/jquery.validate.min.js) to make sure values are checked and plan to implement a required-dependency function for each field in the end.

### My Form:

```
<form name="formtest" action="">
    <table class="background_table">
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>Are you a man?</td>
        <td>
            <input type="radio" name="q1" id="yes1">Yes
            <input type="radio" name="q1" id="no1">No
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Do you have hair?</td>
        <td>
            <input type="radio" name="q2" id="yes2">Yes
            <input type="radio" name="q2" id="no2">No
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>Do you have children?</td>
        <td>
            <input type="radio" name="q3" id="yes3">Yes
            <input type="radio" name="q3" id="no3">No
        </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>

<input type="submit" />
</form>
```

I believe my jQuery function would iterate through all fields (given my actual form has 20+ questions) using the .each() function and then run a test on the individual fields to see if the value was yes:checked. If it was a new row is insert after the field with a blank text area.

I am not quite sure what the best method for naming and identifying the text areas might be at this time. Ultimately, all text area answers could be combined into an array I suppose and broken out by an ID and value but not sure how I'd like to handle that quite yet.

### jQuery function:

```
$(function() {

    $('input').each( function() {
        if( $('#yes1').is(':checked')) { //need to figure out how to find the yes value for each input
            $('#yes1').closest('tr').after('<tr><td colspan="2">Please explain below:<br><textarea name="a1" id="a1"></textarea></td></tr>');
        }
    });


    $("#formtest").validate({
        errorLabelContainer: "#form_error_message",
        wrapper: "li",
        rules: {
            q1: 'required',
            q2: 'required',
            q3: 'required',
            q4: 'required',
            a1: { required: "yes1:checked" },
            a2: { required: "yes2:checked" },
            a3: { required: "yes3:checked" },
            a4: { required: "yes4:checked" }
        },
        messages: {
            //custom messages for all rules above
        },
        submitHandler: function() {
            //Do processing
        }
    });
});
```

My function currently does not work but am looking for guidance as to how this can best be achieved. In the end it may just be easier to present a single text area for explanation of ANY checkbox is answered 'yes' at the end of the form but feel the initial method looks nicer and allows me to separate responses if I wanted.

### final update

Of note, as part of a form, users have the ability to get back to this page. To prevent them having to retype answers and selections, I use PHP SESSION variables to contain previously entered data. I needed to make sure the explanation boxes showed or hid themselves as necessary. To prevent any issues with non-js browsers, I have all my explain boxes display initially then are set to hidden if the value of the corresponding checkbox is not equal to value of 1:

```
$(":radio:checked").each(function() {
    if( $(this).val() != 1) {
       $(this).closest('tr').next().hide();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are only checking on the initial DOM load.  You need to fire off a check on click events so that your box will appear/disappear on click.  I would add a hidden tr row containing each comment box, and then either show or hide as appropriate.  Something like this:

```
$('input:radio').click(function() {
    $commentTr = $(this).closest('tr').next();
    if ($(this).val() == 'Yes')  {
        $commentTr.hide();
    }
    else {
        $commentTr.show();
    }
});
```

On closer inspection, I suppose the check for a value of "Yes" wouldn't quite work.  I'd recommend using HTML label tags with the "for" attribute populated with unique IDs of each input.

```
<input type="radio" name="q1" id="yes1"><label for="yes1">Yes</label>
```

Then you could have a check like:

$('label[for="' + id + '"'].html() == 'Yes'

Comment: good point on firing only on DOM load. I actually just typed that up quickly for demo purposes but valid point nonetheless.

Answer (score 1):

I've set up a [jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/NgBFL/) which I think does what you're looking for.

Comment: Thank you for your answer (and comedy). I am testing out both methods and trying to decide whether I like implementing the hidden approach you have or simply applying as needed via javascript but this does seem to work like I need it to

Comment: Also - changing the answer back to 'no' in your answer does not remove the actual field. I will continue to work with it and likely end up combining answers.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of things to consider with your current solution.  First of all, as Danimal37 mentions, you are only running this on load of the page.  You want the explanation boxes to show/hide whenever the value of each radio button change.  Second of all, there is a built-in way to distinguish between the 'yes' and the 'no'.  Just give the input elements `value` attributes.  To fix these problems, I propose the following (I've ignored the validation portion and you can see it in action in this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xonev/RU986/2/):

```
        // The Javascript
        $('input[value="1"]').change(function () {
            var explainId = $(this).attr('name') + 'explain';
            $(this).closest('tr').after('<tr id="' + explainId + '"><td colspan="2">Please explain below:<br><textarea name="a1" id="a1"></textarea></td></tr>');
        });

        $('input[value="0"]').change(function () {
            var explainId = $(this).attr('name') + 'explain';
            $(this).closest('tr').next('tr#' + explainId).remove();
        });
```

```
<!-- The HTML -->
<form name="formtest" action="">
  <table class="background_table">
    <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Are you a man?</td>
      <td>
        <input type="radio" name="q1" id="yes1" value="1" />Yes
        <input type="radio" name="q1" id="no1" value="0" />No
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Do you have hair?</td>
      <td>
        <input type="radio" name="q2" id="yes2" value="1" />Yes
        <input type="radio" name="q2" id="no2" value="0" />No
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>Do you have children?</td>
      <td>
        <input type="radio" name="q3" id="yes3" value="1" />Yes
        <input type="radio" name="q3" id="no3" value="0" />No
      </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: only issue I face with this however is in creating unique name/ids for the textareas as needed. I believe the above script could be altered as I intend to look at here shortly.

Comment: Good point with the value attribute.  I should have thought of that!  But it still doesn't hurt to mark up labels with semantic HTML, making them clickable as well.